# Application immediately terminates after executing Application_Startup()

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF application, with two methods `Application_Startup` and `Application_Exit` in the `App.cs` file, which are hooked to the `Startup` and `Exit` events of the application respectively. Here's the implementation for these two methods:

```
private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (LoginModel.TryLoginUsingSavedCredentials())
        {
            MainView view = new MainView();
            view.Show();
        }
        else
        {
            LoginView loginView = new LoginView();
            var result = loginView.ShowDialog();

            if (result.HasValue && result.Value)
            {
                MainView view = new MainView();
                view.Show();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (FaultException ex)
    {
        Views.MessageBox.ShowMessage("Login failed",
            string.Format("Unabled to login.\r\n{0}", ex.Message),
            Entities.Enums.DialogType.OK,
            Entities.Enums.DialogIcon.Error);
    }
}

private void Application_Exit(object sender, ExitEventArgs e)
{
    ConnectionFactory.Instance.CloseAllProxyChannels();
}
```

When I run the application, if `LoginModel.TryLoginUsingSavedCredentials()` returns false, the `LoginView` is displayed. Now, I set a breakpoint at `if(result.HasValue ...)` and I step in. `MainView` gets created and `view.Show()` gets executed, however, the debugger arrow jumps immediately to the `Application_Exit` method, and the application terminates. I don't see any exception,output error, dump file, etc.

The weird thing is, if I comment out all the logic in `Application_Startup` and just put these two lines:

```
MainView view = new MainView();
view.Show();
```

Then the application works just fine. Any idea what could be possibly going wrong? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably the auto-shutdown because you effectively close the last window. You can try to change the `Application.ShutdownMode` to `OnExplicitShutdown` while getting the credentials.

(You can also set it to `OnMainWindowClose` permanently and set `Application.MainWindow` to your main view)